# No OS found when I boot with USB

Tags: 12.04, usb, bios

No OS found when I boot with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS USB. I installed Ubuntu with live CD to my USB. I also fail with unetbootin. Also no OS found.

It seems that my computer does not support booting with USB (I don't think so since there is a choice in BIOS called removable device.) I choose the boot with removable device, is it right?

Moreover, I have tried to boot it in Virtualbox and I can load the Ubuntu without any problem. I am using Lenovo H410. Is it the BIOS problem?

Lastly can I install Ubuntu on DVD rw?

Answer (score 0):

Two things could be failing. First, the system could be improperly installed in your USB and second the board could not be trying to boot from the USB. Without more information on the error or the settings in your board it's pretty difficult to determine what's the problem. Try to expand your question with more details.

You can install Ubuntu in a DVD-RW, yes.

Comment: i can use virtualbox, to boot with usb ( just make a new hard drive which is same as my usb )

Comment: The usb should be able to run.(that's whyy i thought it is the problem of bios) 
How to install in a dvd since i only have dvd drive. cannot insert more than 1 dvd- -
in virtualbox, my dvd is not readable since it cannot be mount. Problem with the format?that dvd works well in windows. cannot choose the device in virtualbox. No choice for dvd

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a mac it is probably unlikely your computer won't boot from USB.

There should be a choice in your bios that enables you to change the boot priority. Find that, and you should be able to put the usb as boot priority or something similar. If that is not done, your computer won't boot from usb. If you have found that already and it isn't working, then it could be that you didn't format your usb.

Format it to fat32 using the disk utility and then try using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to change the image into something readable on the usb. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Install gparted (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted).Open gparted from a terminal (sudo gparted).Carefully select the usb drive in the drive dropdown.Right click and select 'manage flags'.Make sure that the 'boot' checkbox is ticked, if not, click it then wait.Reboot the machine and see if it works